# Notation for modeling the price process of risky asset in d-dimensional Black-Scholes model

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, finance

I'm learning the Black-Scholes model as beginner. In our lecture notes, we have following **setting**:

Let $W=(W_t^1,\dots,W_t^d)_{t\in[0,T]}$ be a d-dim standard Brownian motion. The financial market consist of d+1 assets. The asset $S^0$ is a non-risky asset defined by
$$S_0^t = e^{rt}$$
where r models the instantaneous interest rate.

The **risky asset** are modeled by $$S_t^i = S_0^i\text{ }exp\big(\Big(\mu^i-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^d|\sigma^{ij}|^2\Big)t\text{ }+\text{ } \sum_{j=1}^d\sigma^{ij}W_t^j\big)$$
where $S_0^i$ are the initial prices, and $\mu^i$ and $\sigma^{ij}$ are constants, describing "drift" and correlations between the assets, respectively.

**Problem**

-I am clear if we are in the 1-dim BS model.

For $d\ge2$, I am **confused by the index notation** for risky asset, like how do $\mu^i,\sigma,\sigma^{ij}$ look like. Could anyone please explain it in detail, explanation with example will be great.

-In addition, if I want to define the price process of risky asset using BS model as a function with specific equi-distant discretization points recursively, does the following **recursion** seem to be correct?
$$S_{t_{i+1}}=S_{t_i}\text{ }exp\big(\Big(\mu^i-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^d|\sigma^{ij}|^2\Big)\Delta t_{i+1}\text{ }+\text{ } \sum_{j=1}^d\sigma^{ij}\underbrace{\Delta W_{t_i}^j}_{\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Delta t_i)\stackrel{d}=\sqrt{\Delta t_i}\mathcal{N}(0,1)}\big)$$

Comment: Why is $\mu^i$ a problem? About $\sigma\,:$ Take $d=2$ and consider the matrix $$(\sigma^{ij})=\begin{pmatrix}v_1&0\\v_2\,\rho&v_2\,\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\end{pmatrix}\,.$$ What is the volatility of $S^1$ resp. $S^2\,$? What is the correlation between $\log S^1$ and $\log S^2\,$?

Comment: so, the i is just index for $\mu$, cause I'm not quite sure about that, and the dimension of each parameter are not clear for me. Consider for d=2, now we have S, if I have understood correctly, $S^1\text{ and }S^2$ are both sequence of random variables not something like random vectors. And i, j stand for the component of $\sigma$.

Comment: I don't know what the difference is between a sequence of random variables and something like a random vector. Just words. Since you understand the one-dimensional case think as follows: each $S^i$ is a copy of a one-dimensional $S$ and we want those $S^i$ be correlated. That's the reason we need that matrix $\sigma$ and not just a single $\sigma^i$ for each $S^i$.